# Can you use a ngFor with a modulus operator in Angular 2

Tags: html, angular

I'm writing out images to the web page.  Every three images I would like to start a new row.  Does angular 2 support this?

Comment: Yes, it does...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can achieve it by doing following:

```
<div *ngFor="let t of temp(math.ceil(arr.length/3)).fill(); let i = index" class="row">
  <div *ngFor="let item of arr.slice(3*i,3*i + 3);" class="item">
    {{item}}
  </div>
</div>
```

And in your component:

```
export class App {
  temp = Array;
  math = Math;
  arr= [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11];
}
```

Here's working **[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/hKa7P82xZvocU7Jh9HZz?p=preview)**

Answer (score 9):

You can access the index of the iteration from the `*ngFor` like so:

`*ngFor="let x of container; let i = index;"`

you can then reference that index in an `*ngIf` inside of the `*ngFor` to display your new row:

`<div *ngIf="i%3 === 0">`

Comment: i have used your suggestion but is returning always true

Answer (score 2):

Borrowing from both answers, but leaning more on Alex's, here's how I accomplished it in `ng2` (v2.0.1).

`<template ...` is deprecated. Where you see `<template ...` you should use `<ng-template ...` after v5.

```
<template ngFor let-peer [ngForOf]="peers" let-p="index" let-last="last">
  <div class="row" *ngIf="p % 2 === 0">
    <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-6">
      <label><input type="checkbox" ...&nbsp;{{peers[p].name}}</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-6" *ngIf="!last">
      <label><input type="checkbox" ...&nbsp;{{peers[p+1].name}}</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Note that while I get each item from the collection, `let-peer [ngForOf]="peers"`, I don't specifically use it. Instead I use the collection and the index, `let-p="index"`, adding to the index as needed, e.g., `peers[p]` and `peers[p+n]`.

Adjust your modulus as needed. The last row should check to be sure that the first column to the last column is not the *last* item in the iterable.

Comment: Won't this just show the rows are equal to p % 2 === 0?

Comment: works perfect. Just remember that it is now called ng-template. Working on Angular 9